# strcat error "Unhandled exception.."

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My goal with my constructor is to:

open a file
read into everything that exists between a particular string ("%%%%%")
put together each read row to a variable (history)
add the final variable to a double pointer of type char (_stories)
close the file.

However, the program crashes when I'm using strcat. But I can't understand why, I have tried for many hours without result. :/

Here is the constructor code:

```
Texthandler::Texthandler(string fileName, int number) 
        : _fileName(fileName), _number(number)  
{
    char* history = new char[50];

    _stories = new char*[_number + 1]; // rows
    for (int j = 0; j < _number + 1; j++)
    {
        _stories[j] = new char [50]; 
    }
        _readBuf = new char[10000]; 

    ifstream file;
    int controlIndex = 0, whileIndex = 0, charCounter = 0;

    _storieIndex = 0;

    file.open("Historier.txt"); // filename 
    while (file.getline(_readBuf, 10000))
    {
        // The "%%%%%" shouldnt be added to my variables
        if (strcmp(_readBuf, "%%%%%") == 0)
        {
        controlIndex++;
        if (controlIndex < 2)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (controlIndex == 1)
    {
        // Concatenate every line (_readBuf) to a complete history
        strcat(history, _readBuf);
        whileIndex++;
    }

    if (controlIndex == 2)
    {
        strcpy(_stories[_storieIndex], history);

        _storieIndex++;
        controlIndex = 1;
        whileIndex = 0;
        // Reset history variable
        history = new char[50];

    }
}
file.close(); 
}
```

I have also tried with stringstream without results..

Edit: Forgot to post the error message: 
"Unhandled exception at 0x6b6dd2e9 (msvcr100d.dll) in Step3_1.exe: 0xC00000005: Access violation writing location 0c20202d20."
Then a file named "strcat.asm" opens..

Best regards
Robert

Answer (score 2):

You've had a buffer overflow somewhere on the stack, as evidenced by the fact one of your pointers is `0c20202d20` (a few spaces and a `-` sign).

It's probably because:

```
char* history = new char[50];
```

is not big enough for what you're trying to put in there (or it's otherwise not set up correctly as a C string, terminated with a `\0` character).

I'm not entirely certain why you think multiple buffers of up to 10K each can be concatenated into a 50-byte string :-)

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` operates on null terminated `char` arrays.  In the line

```
strcat(history, _readBuf);
```

`history` is uninitialised so isn't guaranteed to have a null terminator.  Your program may read beyond the memory allocated looking for a `'\0'` byte and will try to copy `_readBuf` at this point.  Writing beyond the memory allocated for `history` invokes undefined behaviour and a crash is very possible.

Even if you added a null terminator, the `history` buffer is much shorter than `_readBuf`.  This makes memory over-writes very likely - you need to make `history` at least as big as `_readBuf`.

Alternatively, since this is C++, why don't you use `std::string` instead of C-style `char` arrays?

Comment: Thank you guys! I solved the problem, through your answers! :)

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Since you're a new user I hope you don't mind if I point you towards some notes on [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)